# Выборка значений в DataFrame по нескольким интервалам

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть столбец Time и Count - как методами pandas сделать датафрейм в котором будут только строки с временем скажем от 153000 до 154000 и 175000 до 181000.
Пробую сделать это через циклы - но в огромном файле этот счет занимает очень много времени.
Поэтому хочется узнать, как правильно сделать в пандас.

```
Time    Count
145540  114550
145545  114570
145553  114560
145603  114590
145612  114560
145617  114570
145623  114550
145627  114550
145632  114560
145632  114570
145632  114560
145638  114550
145708  114550
145711  114550
```

Решение по типу `df[(df['Time']>153000) & (df['Time']<154000)` оказавается не слишком надежным

Comment: df[(df['Time']>153000)  & (df['Time']<154000)]

Comment: добавить or  `() | ()`

Comment: Вместо or. Вертикальная черта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `between`:
При:

```
      Time   Count
0   145540  114550
1   145545  114570
2   145553  114560
3   145603  114590
4   145612  114560
5   145617  114570
6   145623  114550
7   145627  114550
8   145632  114560
9   145632  114570
10  145632  114560
11  145638  114550
12  145708  114550
13  145711  114550
```

```
df[df["Time"].between(145500, 145600)]
```

получим:

```
     Time   Count
0  145540  114550
1  145545  114570
2  145553  114560
```

Если нужно использовать сразу несколько интервалов, то могу посоветовать такое решение: указываем интервал индекс с кортежами с пределами - в первом кортеже нижние пределы нужных нам интервалов, во втором - верхние то есть, запись [(145540, 145600), (145550, 145700)] означает два интервала: 145540-145550 и 145600-145700

```
rng = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(145540, 145600), (145550, 145700)])
res = df["Time"].apply(lambda x: any(rng.contains(x)))
```

тогда `df[res]` будет:

```
      Time   Count
1   145545  114570
2   145553  114560
3   145603  114590
4   145612  114560
5   145617  114570
6   145623  114550
7   145627  114550
8   145632  114560
9   145632  114570
10  145632  114560
11  145638  114550
```

Comment: Забыл написать комментарий, что обновил ответ.